# How to do loop based of putting image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is my script

```
function initCanvas(){
var canvasbg = document.getElementById('canvas_background').getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = "";

function drawBox(){
    this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.src = imageObj.src;
    this.render = function(){
        canvasbg.drawImage(imageObj, this.x, this.y);
    }
}

var box = new drawBox();
box.src = "Images/Buildings/PokemonCenter.png";
box.x = 50;
box.y = 50;

function animate(){
    box.render();
}

var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 30);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event){
initCanvas();
 });
```

I tried to put the src under the `imageObj.src = "Images/Buildings/PokemonCenter.png";`.

Then yes it's working there but when I tried to put in the box.src it's not showing up.

Is there a way to do it? So I cannot flood my script with a lot of function of drawImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not showing up using `box.src` because it is not defined when `drawBox` is specified. You need to rethink your structure. A better way of approaching this would be using something like this:

```
function drawBox (parameters) {
     this.x = parameters.x || 0, 
     this.y = parameters.y || 0;
     this.image = new Image();
     this.image.src = parameters.src || "";
     this.render = function (canvas) {
         canvas.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
     }
}

var box = new drawBox({
    x: 50, 
    y: 50,
    src: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b1c8ae5b2e357e18d61bfb0dfd39136c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
});

function animate(){
    box.render(canvasbg);
}
```

This way you are sending dynamic parameters to the `drawBox` function and it can fall back to its default values if they're not specified. The render function is also a bit easier to use as you can specify what canvas to render the image onto in your `animate` function. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/fwk9ukkz/1/) a working fiddle.

Comment: I'm sorry, still learning js, what is the use of that 'parameters'? Haven't encountered it yet

Comment: @user3323654 It's a common pattern in Javascript to pass all parameters of a function in form of a single object. This allows for better code readability of the function call, because all parameters are named.

Comment: How about the logical operator?

Comment: Ohh i get it! If there's no value that has been passed, the value of it would be zero.

Comment: Is the name 'parameters' of it, final?

Comment: What do you mean by final in this context? 'parameters' is just a standard name for initialising values in this way (like Philipp mentioned), but you can add other properties to drawBox if you'd like.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of some help :)

Comment: What if, I want to change again the source of the image? I mean change the image for example when I pressed a key then it will change image. Something like that? How to access the src?

Comment: Have a play around with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fwk9ukkz/3/), I've commented some code for you.